# Como desvincular o diretório local de repositório remoto?

Tags: git, github

Preciso trocar de máquina e desvincular o diretório local do repositório para usá-lo somente em uma outra máquina.

Como posso fazer essa desvinculação?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você pode:

1. Apagar o diretório da máquina. Assim o computador não terá mais o código fonte e, consequentemente, será impossível fazer alguma alteração.
2. Remover o `remote` do repositório local.

   ```
   git remote rm origin
   ```

   Como o GIT é um sistema de versionamento distribuído, todos que fizeram um `clone` do repositório remoto têm **um repositório próprio**. O que acontece é que as modificações feitas nestes repositórios próprios são refletidas para o repositório central sempre que é feito um `push` (de forma análoga, o `pull` faz o processo inverso).

   Fazer com que o repositório local não tenha mais um `remote` impede que sejam feitos `push`s e `pull`s.

Comment: Valew cara, me ajudou bastante ;)